# I can't copy values to the next column on the same row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new on VBA and i need some help. I've found this code and i adapted it to my needs, but the issue is that i can't copy the first 100 cells to the next column on the same row in a table(the column E is already filled and i want to paste the values to the column F).

here is the code:

```
Sub variable_to_check()
Dim j As Integer, r As Range, k As Integer, dest As Range
j = 100
With Worksheets("Calibrari")
    Set r = .Range("A2")
    k = 0
    Do
        Range(r, r.Offset(j - 1, 0)).copy
        With Worksheets("INCA")
            Set dest = .Cells(Rows.count, "F").Offset(0, 0).End(xlUp).Offset(0, -1)
            dest.PasteSpecial

            'this add the text "INCA_Read" in the first column after each 100 cells 
            lr = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count, "E").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            ActiveSheet.Cells(lr, "A").value = "INCA_Read"

            If k < .Range("F13").Column - 2 Then
            k = k + 1
            Else
                k = 0
            End If
        End With
        Set r = r.Offset(j, 0)
        If r = .Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) Then Exit Do
    Loop
End With 
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("INCA").Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub

Sub value_to_be_checked() <--in this macro i think the issue is

Dim j As Integer, r As Range, k As Integer, dest As Range
j = 100
With Worksheets("Calibrari")
    Set r = .Range("C2")
    k = 0
    Do
        Range(r, r.Offset(j - 1, 0)).copy
        With Worksheets("INCA")
            Set dest = .Cells(Rows.count, "E").Offset(0, 0).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1)
            dest.PasteSpecial

            If k < .Range("E13").Column - 2 Then
                k = k + 1
            Else
                k = 0
            End If
        End With
        Set r = r.Offset(j, 0)
        If r = .Range("C2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) Then Exit Do
    Loop
End With

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: Add a `.` in front of `Range(r, r.Offset(j - 1, 0)).copy`

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work

Comment: I think you need to clarify things for us. You want to copy the first 100 rows of column `E` on which worksheet? Your code seems to do more than that. You nest two `with Worksheets`, which may work, but feels odd and may easily cause confusion (in my simple mind, at least). Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52319105/edit) your post and add sample data and expected outcome?

Comment: i'm sorry that i haven't replied until now. I want to copy the first 100 rows from column A, sheet "Calibrari" to column E in "INCA" sheet and after each 100 rows to place into column A the text "INCA_Read". Also, i want to copy the first 100 rows from column C("Calibrari" sheet) into column F("INCA" sheet). I hope that i've clarified the misunderstandings. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Copy/Paste, just set the value of the cell:

```
Worksheets("INCA").Cells(Rows.count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) = Range(r, r.Offset(j - 1, 0)).Value2
```

Comment: it place only the first value in column F after that 100 cells in the column E. The column E has values from the E15 to E114, and the first value in column F is placed in F115, not in F15.

Comment: Change the "0" in the first Offset statement to "j-1".

Comment: I made that change it will copy the values that already are in the "INCA" sheet, but into another cell in the same sheet(i mean in the "INCA" sheet)